# Count to return Multiple Colums as SQL Query

Tags: sql, count

Very new to this but here goes,

I have written the following to count all records against a date by a status using the below,

```
Select trunc(create_date_time) as "CREATED DATE", count(*) as Cancelled
from TASK_HDR
where WHSE = 102 and INVN_NEED_TYPE = 101 and STAT_CODE = 99
    and trunc(create_date_time)>= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1)
Group BY trunc(create_date_time)
order by trunc(create_date_time) asc;

Select trunc(create_date_time) as "CREATED DATE", count(*) as Released
from TASK_HDR
where WHSE = 102 and INVN_NEED_TYPE = 101 and STAT_CODE = 10
    and trunc(create_date_time)>= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1)
Group BY trunc(create_date_time)
order by trunc(create_date_time) asc;
```

What I am trying to do is create this so that I return one query with the results side by side

```
Date       Outstanding   Completed
04-JAN-21       1            10
05-JAN-21       2            12
06-JAN-21       7            15
08-JAN-21       1            8
11-JAN-21       4            7
01-FEB-21       3            3
02-FEB-21       6            1
04-FEB-21       6            0
```

I really appreciate the help with this,

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Use `case` expressions to do *conditional aggregation*:

```
Select trunc(create_date_time) as "CREATED DATE",
       sum(case when STAT_CODE = 99 then 1 else 0 end) as Cancelled,
       sum(case when STAT_CODE = 10 then 1 else 0 end) as Released
from TASK_HDR
where WHSE = 102 and INVN_NEED_TYPE = 101 and STAT_CODE in (99, 10)
    and trunc(create_date_time)>= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1)
Group BY trunc(create_date_time)
order by trunc(create_date_time) asc;
```

Comment: This works perfectly, apologies for the Noob Question. :)

Comment: @GeoffBird, please mark it as answer, so it is helpful for others in future